# Flutter shorten a string

Tags: flutter

I have a string showing the date and time, but I only want to see the hour and minute. how do i do this with flutter.Sorry if there are other questions that I missed.

```
String? time = "2023-02-21 14:50:40";
```

Result:

```
String? time = "14:50";
```

I tried to try with regex but failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the quickest way is using the built-in `DateTime.parse()`:

```
  final dt = DateTime.parse('2023-02-21 14:50:40');
  final result = '${dt.hour}:${dt.minute}';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
void main() {
String? time = "2023-02-21 14:50:40";
DateTime tempDate =  DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse(time);
String? hourTime = tempDate.hour.toString();
String? minuteTime = tempDate.minute.toString();
print(hourTime); //14
print(minuteTime); //50
}
```

You can use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package for convert `string` to `datetime`.